# Is it viable to become a freelance developer right after graduating?

Tags: software-industry

Next year I'll graduate from a BSc + Masters (MEng) course in Computer Science and am seriously considering starting off as a freelance developer right after that and keep on it for a year or two maybe.

Do you think this is a reasonable idea? Would a university graduate like me with little (but some) real experience in the industry find it hard to get freelance contracts?

Any tips, advice, pointers...?

Comment: This is likely going to be closed because it's off topic.  Yes, you'll likely find it hard to get contracts if you're starting off with no contacts and little experience.  Getting contracts when you have a ton of experience and a lot of contacts is hard.  That doesn't, of course, mean that it's impossible, particularly if you're willing to go through agencies rather than being purely freelance.

Comment: As currently edited, this doesn't appear to be off topic. You can get contract work right out of college - the 'Can Opener' is Microsoft Access VBA.  In short, if you're familiar with C++ and JavaScript and Python, so are a lot of people that want to work in it, so you'd better be good. 'Real Programmers' 'don't do Access' - not really a true statement, but a lot of people resist getting mixed up with it.  A lot of small businesses need it, however. The experience is good regardless of the language - don't fixate on that too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certainly sites that you can sign up for to try and bid on jobs.  I'm not sure what country you are in, so the prices being paid for that type of work might, or might not be acceptable.  As an example, a few weeks ago someone showed me a work request for a site like FB and the bids on it were in the $1000US range...  I call that insanity; others might jump for it.

Either way, I'd suggest you don't start off this way.

Development takes quite a bit of experience before you really get a good grip on how long things should take.  When you are working as a regular full time employee, that subjective amount of time isn't really important to your take home pay.

As a free lance developer, there are essentially two ways of bidding on a project.

Fixed bid - meaning they pay X and you deliver Y.  If it takes longer then you made less per hour; if it takes less then bonus.  I once made a disaster of a mistake and bid a project so low that I ended up making about $2/hour on it.  Neither I nor the client was happy about that deal.

The next is Time and Materials - meaning you work for X an hour and bill the client on an ongoing basis.  Even then you'll have to estimate how long a project will take.  If you go over budget while not delivering the client is going to end up really unhappy.  Again, experience is the best guide for how long things take.

It might sound like a way to make a lot of money fairly quickly; and, honestly, it can be.  But first off you really really need to know exactly what you are doing.  That's the only way you'll come out ahead instead of feeling like you'd be better of working at a fast food joint.

Bear in mind that clients can be fickle.  Sometimes you might bill a client and have to wait 30, 60 or 90+ days before seeing a penny.  My company has a client that is nearly a year behind on their payment...  At some point you'll have one take the work and run away.  Certainly some will do everything they can to pressure you to do more than you agreed to without paying for it.  And others will absolutely insist that you do things in a way that you know just isn't going to work out, then turn around and blame you when it fails.

Yes, there are good clients.  Well, I'm pretty sure I've had a couple anyway.. :)

My main point is simply that a regular FTE job can provide a lot of real world training, resources and experience without having to gamble your paycheck.   Which a freelance developer does every single time they take on a client.

So, get some "safe" experience then dip your toes in while working a full time job at the same time.  You'll have steady income and if the inevitable happens then it's not that big a loss.  Once you've built up a recurring client list, then take the leap.

Comment: +1: no degree is a substitute for the real-world job experience you need to accurately judge projects and clients before you take them.

Answer (score 2):

I would have rather added a comment to Chris' answer than adding this answer. There is also the problem of liability when it comes to going it on your own. Like Chris said, clients can be fickle and some can be down right nasty to the point that they will want to bring litigation and sue you.

It is much safer to be employed and do some small time personal work on the side in order to build up your base skills, clientele, reputation, and gain the experience of what real world demands from customers can be like.

Another way to think about this is simple: would you rather a seasoned professional to work on your car, or the bright eyed wannabe with no history besides good grades in a classroom environment to fix your engine?

Now if you are particularly confident in your abilities, you could hit up sites like Sourceforge or Freecode and demonstrate your ability by posting functional contributions. Be aware that you would be entering the open source community by doing so, but should you be successful you will have a rapid gain of reputation and name base.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think this is a reasonable idea?

You don't give what I'd see as a few key details to determine this:

- What kind of network do you have in terms of clients and possible work coming to you soon? Some people may have lots of friends that want some help that may be a useful way to build up a reputation.
- What kind of niche do you plan on covering? Would you write software that could take over the world in a couple of weeks with guaranteed success?
- What kind of reputation do you currently have? Are you that "go to guy"?
- Do you have a plan? For example, are you going for contract positions through a recruiting firm, bidding for jobs on sites like odesk or elance, or getting paid under the table?

> Would a university graduate like me with little (but some) real
>   experience in the industry find it hard to get freelance contracts?

Depending on your geography, reputation, plan and other things, I could imagine a wide range of possible answers. If you are in the top .0001% of programmers worldwide, I'd think it may be possible to get companies bidding to have you come to them. However, if you aren't in that top ballpark, don't have a big network and don't have a niche you may have issues.

> Should I do it or not do it?

How much are you going to put on the line to work this way? For example, how would you handle living expenses if you took you 18 months to get our first contract?

> Any tips, advice, pointers...?

Consider what plan do you have, what kind of stuff you want to do and how much do you think you're worth here carefully.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a university graduate like me with little (but some) real
>   experience in the industry find it hard to get freelance contracts?

It's reasonable, but you will certainly find it very hard to get contracts - particularly initially.

Freelancers generally rely on their reputation and contacts as aids in securing contracts. Right now, you have little or none.

Perhaps you have a network of friends that can help you get started. At least you need to be prepared financially for some lean times early on.